# url rewriting asp .htaccess file

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I just moved my website (asp.net) to the live environment. I realized they are running IIS 6 so all my nice and clean url rewriting doesn't work anymore. I was trying to implement URL rewriting using the .htaccess file.

I want to rewrite:

www.amicobio.co.uk/Menu.aspx to www.amicobio.co.uk/Food-Menu

So in .htaccess I set:

```
CaseInsensitive On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Food-Menu$ Menu.aspx
```

But it doesn't work it says:

> The requested URL
>   /a/m/amicobio.co.uk/public/Menu.aspx
>   was not found on this server.

Obviously the path is wrong but what is /a/m/ and how do I fix it? All the files in amicobio.co.uk/public/

Thanks.

Comment: And where does your .htaccess reside? Consider playing with the URL base as it seems to be the issue.

Comment: same folder as the other files amicobio.co.uk/public/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

it was

RewriteRule ^Food-Menu /Menu.aspx

in stead of

RewriteRule ^Food-Menu$ Menu.aspx